# window onload & function scroll page not work

Tags: javascript

I need to do this in pure javascript, no jquery, but it does not work...

```
window.onload= function(){
  if (window.pageYOffset >=300){
    window.scroll(0, 300);
    alert('ok');
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Have a look at this cool jQuery plugin here.](http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/)

Comment: I've already maded it in jQuery way, but I need to do it in pure JS!

Comment: May I ask why? You'll just be doing the same thing jQuery is dong, except battling with all the browser compatibility they've already won the battle against. :O

Comment: what is the jQuery scroll() equivalent in Javascript? please I need it

Comment: `scrollTop()` and I was able to get your base scroll to work **[in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/jscu9/)** I am just trying to figure out, so if the page has scrolled down _past_ 300, snap it to 300?

Comment: finally I found a solution here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll#Example_2.3A_Detecting_a_scroll

Comment: Haha! Glad you found a solution. Just as I wrote you a pure JS version. Haha See below. You should post your solution though so you can accept the answer in 2 days, or accept mine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain JavaScript method that snaps to scrolls position `300` if you scroll past the position `300`

```
function scrollCycle() {
    var cycle = setInterval(function() {
        var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
              document.body.scrollTop;
        if ( top >= 300 ) {
            window.scroll(0,300);
        }
    }, 200);
}

scrollCycle();
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/jscu9/)

Or by detecting a scroll

```
function scrollCycle() {
        var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
              document.body.scrollTop;
        if ( top >= 300 ) {
            window.scroll(0,300);
        }
}

window.onscroll = scrollCycle;
```

Which will not let you past position `300`

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/9mNgm/)